# ngModel not working on checkbox bound to array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

i have an array of objects with one property Boolean. trying to bind this property to checkbox i snot working .

see below plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/dsQQCJrQD5kfOwcsCzze

i get and error

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import **`FormsModule`**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule ,FormsModule],
declarations: [ App ],
bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

**[`WORKING DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/1rSaZMNS3wFBvhNEKoOG?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox input you can use `[checked]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`
Also, you can use `(change)` instead of `([ngModelChange)]`

```
<input class="checkbox binning-checkbox" type="checkbox"  
            (change)="select(item)" [checked]="item.selected">
```

Checkout [the plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/igBlC7JK55cdqKrkFIGE?p=preview)

Comment: if i do this the "select" method is not called.

Comment: i am trying to unselect the checkbox when it is selected
 public select(item){
    alert(item.name);
    item.selected = false;
  }

Comment: You need to use `(change)` for that. Checkout the updated answer and the updated plunker.

Comment: check this out 
https://plnkr.co/edit/WdtFF96B5GJScFYMQFzG
the "selected" property is false it should be true because we recently checked it.

Comment: I am checking if it's a trivial problem in your code, but I think that is not what your original question was. Your original question gets resolved by using `(change)` and `[checked]`. You can verify by the alert being executed and if you set any of the `selected` values to true, the checkbox will already be checked.

Comment: I am checking if it's a trivial problem in your code, but I think that is not what your original question was. Your original question gets resolved by using `(change)` and `[checked]`. You can verify by the alert being executed and if you set any of the `selected` values to true, the checkbox will already be checked.